# How to assign numbers to words in java?

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, numbers, assign

I have a problem about the last part of the code. I want to assign numbers to specific words but i always get 0 value, even though I get those strings from the first System.out.println  correctly,  i cannot get the numerical equivalents of those strings at the second System.out.println.Any ideas how to solve this problem?

```
public static double number;

protected void myMethod(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    String speech= request.getParameter("speech");
    System.out.println("The recognized speech is : "+ speech);

    // There is no problem till here.
    if(speech == "Hi")
        number = 1 ;
    if(speech== "Thanks")
        number = 2 ;
    if(speech== "Bye")
        number = 0 ;

    System.out.println("The number for the speech is : " + number);
}
```

However here i dont get the correct numbers but only 0 for each word!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `==` operator to check if two Strings have the same value in Java, you need to use the `.equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()` methods instead:

```
if("Hi".equalsIgnoreCase(speech)) {
    number = 1;
}
else if("Thanks".equalsIgnoreCase(speech)) {
    number = 2;
}
else if("Bye".equalsIgnoreCase(speech)) {
    number = 0;
}
else {
    number = -1;
}
```

The reason for this is that the `==` operator compares *references*; that is it will return `true` if and only if the *instance* stored in variable `speech` is the *same instance* as the literal String you've created between double quotes (`"Hi"`, `"Thanks"`, or `"Bye"`).

Note also that I use the `equalsIgnoreCase()` call on the literal String I'm declaring, rather than the variable that is assigned from the parameter. This way, if a `speech == null`, the method call is still valid (`"Hi"` will *always* be a `String`), and so you won't get a `NullPointerException`, and the flow will continue until the `else` branch.

Answer (score 4):

The == will only be true if the Strings are the same object. Use:

```
if(speech.equals("Hi"))
```

or to match without case:

```
if(speech.equalsIgnoreCase("hi"))
```

Comment: Then speech is `null` which you should check first. Or of course you can use `if("Hi".equals(speech))` or `if("hi".equalsIgnoreCase(speech))`

`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet:

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<StringWithValue> stringList = new ArrayList<StringWithValue>();
        stringList.add(new StringWithValue("Hi", 1));
        stringList.add(new StringWithValue("Thanks", 2));
        stringList.add(new StringWithValue("Bye", 3));

        String speech = "Hi";
        int number = 0;

        for(StringWithValue swv : stringList){
            if(swv.getString().equals(speech)){
                number = swv.getValue();
                break;
            } else {
                number = -1;
        }

        System.out.println("The number for the speech is : " + number);
    }
}
```

StringWithValue.java

```
public class StringWithValue {
    private String string;
    private int value;

    public StringWithValue(String string, int value) {
        this.string = string;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getString() {
        return string;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you not use an `enum` instead of your `StringWithValue` class?

Comment: of course, with the same result, but in this case you can't just use the foreach to go through all the enum entries, so i prefer the way using a class and the foreach

Comment: Yes, but you'd have the advantage of not having to write and maintain another class, and you could `switch` on it in Java 1.6 and earlier.

Comment: depends on whether you have to run it with 1.6 and earlier. either way, you would also have to maintain the enum.

Answer (score -2):

```
public static double number;

    if(speech=="hi")
    {
        number=1;
    }
    else if(speech=="thanks")
    {
        number=2;
    }
    else if(speech=="Bye")
    {
        number=0;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Word Not Found");
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not help :/